# Не работает каскадность в ActiveAndroid

Tags: android, orm

Использую ORM ку ActiveAndroid в своем проекте. Возникала проблема, что не работает каскадность. Мало того, что я не нашел каскадного инсерта, так и существующие каскадности обновления и удаления так же не работают. Например так я указываю каскадность:

```
@Column(name = "purchaseCalculation", onDelete = Column.ForeignKeyAction.CASCADE, onUpdate = Column.ForeignKeyAction.CASCADE)
```

Но по факту каскадность срабатывает только для вложенности на 1 уровень. Например есть класс `User`, он содержит в себе массив объектов `Item`, которые в свою очередь содержат `Info`. Я удаляю `User` и ожидаю, что удалятся все связанные объекты, но по факту удаляются только `Item`, а `Info` остается.

А так же есть ли способ делать каскадный инсерт?

Comment: Покажите скрипт создания таблиц - скорее всего проблема там.

Comment: какой скрипт? вы работали с ActiveAndroid?

Comment: Чтобы разобраться с каскадным удалением/вставкой необязательно знать именно `ActiveAndroid` - достаточно понимать общие принципы. Интересует скрипт `create table`, который генерирует ваш ORM

Comment: Видемо все ORM всетаки разные, потому как я не пишу ни каких скриптов. все создается атвоматически. Я анатирую классы и екстендюсь от класса Model. ормка делает все сама. каскадность указывается в анотациях к полям. просто загляните в доки ормки, может вы лучше поймете чем я. может я чтото упустил, и мои товарищи
https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/wiki/Creating-your-database-model  первая ссылка в гугле

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ найден. Это не возможно. делать надо так [ссылка](http://blog.robinchutaux.com/blog/using-retrofit-with-activeandroid/)